# Alt keys not working properly in Citrix Workspace under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, citrix

I'm using Citrix Workspace on Ubuntu 20.04 (while loggin on to a Windows environment). Everything works fine, except that there's a problem with the ALT keys. It appears as if Citrix was sending both left and right ALT keys at the same time, whichever key I'm pressing. As a result, some applications are confused and interprete the ALT-key combination as a menu shorthand, while others interprete it as a special character keystroke. With the current situation, I can't properly type \, {, }, #, @, etc. I tried modifying some values in All_Regions.ini, but either I'm using the wrong keys/values, or they don't have any effect.

Relevant section in All_Regions.ini:

```
[Virtual Channels\Keyboard]
TransparentKeyPassthrough=
KeyPassthroughEscapeChar=
KeyPassthroughEscapeShift=
UseLocalIM=
KeyboardLayout=
KeyboardType=
KeyboardSendLocale=
KeyboardTimer=*
UseEUKS=*
UseEUKSforASCII=*
SETLEDPos=4
EUKSModeMask=*
ScancodeEnabled=*
KeyboardMappingFile=
UnicodeKeyboard=
LocaleKeyMapping=
SuperMetaToWinKeys=
RightSuperMetaToWinKey=
BalanceShiftKeys=*
BalancedShiftMask=*
EchoShiftKeys=*
MSLocaleNumber=*
BypassSetLED=
ServerDoesMultiMod=*
BloombergRedirection=*
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this Citrix support article](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX219689) and see if it works for you also.

- Log into Windows and type "ease" (and select **Ease of access center**)
- Select **Make my keyboard easier to use**
- Select **Turn on Filter Keys** checkbox
- Click on **Set up Filter Keys** (opens new window)
- Select **Turn on Filter Keys** checkbox (in the new window).
- Click **Set up Repeat Keys and Slow Keys** (opens new window).
- Click **Ignore all Repeated Keystrokes**
- Under the header **Avoid Accidental Keystrokes** set it to "0.0 Seconds"
- Click Apply

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed an issue with the Citrix client, where both the left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys are interpreted the same. This makes it more difficult to enter foreign characters under the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, sometimes labeled as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, the Alt Graph key.

That is probably due to how the communication between your console and the Citrix server is set up. As a work around, you still can enter AltGr characters by

1. Pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and releasing it
2. Pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> again in combination with the key needed for the special character.

Where possible, you can rely on the dead key combinations, which work as usual in Citrix applications.

Comment: Hm, that's a pity. Is this issue documented somewhere, is there a bugtracker?